# Python search and copy files in directory

Tags: python, file, search, directory, copy

I'm new to python so please excuse my ignorance.

I am looking to create a way of searching one text file for a list of files that conform to search criteria. Then using the results to search a through/recurse directory for those files, and copy them all into one master folder.

Essentially I have a text file that has loads of file names, I have managed to search through the file and retrieve all the files ending with '.mov', and print/output the result to a text file. There may be dozens of files.

How can I then use those results to recursively search through a directory and copy the files to a new location.

Or, am I going about this in totally the wrong way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
import os, shutil

# First, create a list and populate it with the files
# you want to find (1 file per row in myfiles.txt)
files_to_find = []
with open('myfiles.txt') as fh:
    for row in fh:
        files_to_find.append(row.strip)

# Then we recursively traverse through each folder
# and match each file against our list of files to find.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for _file in files:
        if _file in files_to_find:
            # If we find it, notify us about it and copy it it to C:\NewPath\
            print 'Found file in: ' + str(root)
            shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + _file), 'C:\\NewPath\\')
```

You'll never learn to be a good programmer by asking "how do i do this" without trying to find out yourself. I usually reccomend people to break the prioblem down into peaces..

- Google: Python List files in directory
- Fiddle around with example codes and see what works best

Then move on,

- Google: Python copy file
- Fiddle around with premade paths, and see if you can get the logic to work

Then combine them both.